# Воспроизводить видео youtube из списка

Tags: java, android, youtube

Есть список с preview'шками видео из youtube.

```
void getIdUrl(String url, int position) {
    String video_id = "";
    String expression = "";
    if (url != null && url.trim().length() > 0 && url.matches(".*\\byoutube\\b.*")) {
        expression = "^.*((youtu.be" + "\\/)" + "|(v\\/)|(\\/u\\/w\\/)|(embed\\/)|(watch\\?))\\??v?=?([^#\\&\\?]*).*";
        CharSequence input = url;
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expression, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            String groupIndex1 = matcher.group(7);
            if (groupIndex1 != null && groupIndex1.length() == 11)
                video_id = groupIndex1;
            ImageUpload imageUpload = new ImageUpload();
            imageUpload.setLoadImage(true);
            OutputMetadata outputMetadata = new OutputMetadata();
            outputMetadata.setVideoUrl("http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + video_id + "/0.jpg");
            outputMetadata.setFilename("http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + video_id + "/0.jpg");
            imageUpload.setOutputMetadata(outputMetadata);
            controlList.get(position).getImageUploads().add(0,imageUpload);
            adapterForm.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

Задача состоит в том, чтобы **по клику на элемент в списке открывалось выбранное видео youtube**.

Пробовал прямо в `adapter`'е реализовывать нажатие по картинке следующим образом:

```
viewHolder.photo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hxy8BZGQ5Jo")));
                    Log.i("Video", "Video Playing....");
                }
            });
```

Возможно метод и рабочий, но выделяет `startActivity` красным.

Также нашёл нечто подобное:

```
        public static void watchYoutubeVideo(String id){
        Intent appIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("vnd.youtube:" + id));
        Intent webIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + id));
        try {
            startActivity(appIntent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            startActivity(webIntent);
        }
    }
```

Но не получается *корректно* вставить его в мой метод `getIdUrl`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В конструктор адаптера добавляете `Context`:

```
private Context mContext;
...
public MyAdapter(Context context) {
      mContext = context;     
 }
```

И далее:

```
mContext.startActivity(...);
```

Comment: Спасибо за реакцию, а если видео не только из youtube, просто используем в методе onClick switch, подставляя индивидуальный Uri.parse?

Comment: Да, как-то так.

Comment: а возможно запилить в onClick мой метод getIdUrl? Чтобы он сразу и проверял ссылки?

Comment: Чтобы ответить на этот вопрос, нужно хорошо знать контекст задачи. Если я правильно понимаю, то Ваш метод `getIdUrl(...)` проверяет `url` и добавляет превью видео в список. Так вот, Вы хотите при нажатии на превью еще раз что-то проверять? Но зачем? Вы же при добавлении превью уже проверяли.

Comment: Потому как на данный момент у меня в методе onClick ссылка по умолчанию стоит {startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hxy8BZGQ5Jo")));}  а мне нужно так раз открывать видео из списка которые уже загружены пользователем. Проще говоря по нажатию открывать вставленные в список видео(список каждый раз разный). А не открывать одно и то же видео вне зависимости от выбранного элемента.

Comment: Тогда можно поступить так: при клике на превью видео получаете ссылку на это видео, проверяете ее и действуете нужным образом. В чем проблема?

Comment: по сути получается что придётся дублировать код из getIdUrl?

Comment: Зачем дублировать? Почему не вызвать непосредственно сам метод `getIdUrl(...)`?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47055/discussion-between-vadim-morozov-and-post-zeew).

Comment: А знаете почему я толком не понимаю, чего Вы хотите? Потому что, судя по названию, метод `getIdUrl(...)` **должен возвращать** `Id`. Я Вам как-то уже говорил об этом. Если Вы хотите, чтобы другие люди смогли понять Вас и Ваш код – именуйте переменные и методы осмысленно (в соответствии с их предназначением).